Díasable an option from a dropdown if it has a specific text on it
function createDropdown() {
  

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");

  const cell = sheet.getRange("G4");
  const rangeList = ss.getRange("'Form'!N5:N8")

  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInRange(rangeList)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .setHelpText("Please select only from the dropdown")
    .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);


}


I'm looking to disable all options that is "Occupied".

You want the occupied items in the list to display, just not be able to be selected?

There is no turnkey way to disable an option in a dropdown so that it is displayed in the list but cannot be selected.
The easiest solution would be to only include options that are actually available. In the example you show, the list would include Star, Desert and Ascension but not Outback.
You can use the filter() function to put the desired options in a range of cells, and point the dropdown list to that range. The dropdown list will automatically ignore unfilled cells in the range.

I'll try that! I'm gonna go ahead and watch some videos on how to use filter function cause I'm no programmer, I'm just watching YouTube videos on how to use scripting. Thanks for the help!

The filter() function can be used in a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula so there is no need to write a script.

Try it this way:
function createDropdown101(txt="8") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const cell = sh.getRange("G4");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A5:A8");
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues().flat().filter(e => !e.includes(txt)).filter(e => e);
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(vs)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .setHelpText("Please select only from the dropdown")
    .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}

